# Error 4605 on opening Word document when another document is already open

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

So I have this problem on the error handler when I want to open a specific word document.

What the program does so far when I start it is: First time start is fine. Then when I run again the program keeps loading until I manually close Word. And after that Word gives me and option to access the file in read-only mode.

I've searched on forums and MSDN for a few hours now and can't find a solution.

Also it keeps giving me

> error code 4605

when I run the code a second time.

Code:

```
Sub OpenWord()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
WordApp.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")
WordApp.Visible = True
Exit Sub

''just for testing
VariableCheese = 5 + 5

ErrorHandler:
WordApp.Documents.Close <<< Here it gives error 4605
WordApp.Quit
Resume Next

End Sub
```

final edit:
Thanks to @Brett I've found a solution. I copied his code and removed the following lines (tagged with >>>):

```
Sub final()

    Set TestDoc = GetObject("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")
>>>>If TestDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set Wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Wd Is Nothing Then
        Set Wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        If Wd Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Failed to start Word!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        >>>>f = True
    **Else** Added line
        **MsgBox "Failed to start Word!", vbCritical** Added line
    End If
    >>>Set TestDoc = Wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")
    >>>If TestDoc Is Nothing Then
        >>>MsgBox "Failed to open help document!", vbCritical
        >>>If f Then
            >>>Wd.Quit
        >>>End If
        >>>Exit Sub
    End If
    Wd.Visible = True
>>>Else
    >>>With WordDoc.Parent
        >>>.Visible = True
        >>>.Activate
    >>>End With
>>>End If

End sub
```

This code opens the file once and then not again until you close it.
But for some reason this line is required `Set TestDoc = GetObject("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")`. If not the Word document will become read-only.

Comment: Does ActiveDocument.Close work? But each time your document opens successfully the file remains open?

Comment: ActiveDocument.Close does not work sadly. The file remains open yes. But when I run the code if it's open it should close and re-open. And it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by going to File > Options > General and see if there is a check mark in the box: `Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view`. If there is, remove it.

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_windows8-mso_2013_release/run-time-error-4605-in-word-2013-no-information/1ca02c04-5cea-484e-bd23-f4d18183c1b2

That said, My feel is that you are trying to close a document that has already been closed (or not active) or that there is no error.

To remedy this check there is an an error:

```
If Err <> 0 Then
  ''Insert your error handling code here
  Err.Clear
Resume Next
```

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/813983/you-receive-run-time-error-4248-4605-or-5941-when-you-try-to-change-pr

Alternatively, the problem is that you are not checking to see if the document is already opened. This likely results in a continuous loop. I suggest using code similar to the example below to detect if the document is already opened.

```
Set TestDoc = GetObject("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")
If TestDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set Wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Wd Is Nothing Then
        Set Wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        If Wd Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Failed to start Word!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        f = True
    End If
    Set TestDoc = Wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")
    If TestDoc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to open help document!", vbCritical
        If f Then
            Wd.Quit
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Wd.Visible = True
Else
    With WordDoc.Parent
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With
End If
```

This code will activate the document if it is already opened.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29265e5f-8df9-4cab-8984-1afb9b110d2f/in-excel-use-vba-to-check-if-a-word-document-is-open?forum=isvvba

Based on your new information another possible cause is that Visual Basic has established a reference to Word because of a line of code that calls a Word object, method, or property without qualifying the element with a Word object variable. Visual Basic does not release this reference until you end the program. This errant reference interferes with automation code when the code is run more than one time. To fix this, change the code so each call to a Word object, method, or property is qualified with the appropriate object variable.

The nearest to explain this is an Excel article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs

To help you more I would need to know:

1. What version of Word you are using.
2. Are you using MacOS or Windows.
3. What are your macro security settings?
4. If you kill all Word process does the error still show?
5. Is the document is ready only or otherwise protected?
6. If you open the document and it's in the active window when you go to the Developer tab and run your macro does the error still occur?

Given we know the document keeps getting protected try removing protection by going into the trust center and ensuring Word 2003/7 Binary Documents and Templates is not ticked.

Comment: Try it in print view and see if the problem is solved (or not). Also, what did you try?

Comment: Doing this `File > Options > General and see if there is a check mark in the box: Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view. If there is, remove it.` actually crashed the PC after running the code...

Comment: I tried doing this:

`If Err <> 0 Then
      ''Insert your error handling code here
      Err.Clear
    Resume Next`

But now it gives me error code 4248 or 462.

Comment: I have added another possible answer. Again, I need more information to help you. I am off to bed soon so please reply ASAP.

Comment: @Brett to anser your questions: 1. Word 2016; 2. Windows; 3. Last box is checked and trust access to objectmodel in vba is checked; 4. yes; 5. no

Comment: Have a read of this https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/189618/you-may-receive-the-run-time-error-2147023174-800706ba-error-message-o the more I hear about your problem the more it looks to be an object referencing problem.

Comment: Also please answer question 6.

Comment: The same error occurs as when I run the program twice. But that is to be expected.

Comment: That tells the error has nothing to do with the document being invisible. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/unable-to-run-a-macro-error-message-run-time-error/1c8cabaf-e3d8-415a-a6a4-007713416d3b (again hinting at referencing or a protected document).

Comment: But I never said it had anything to do with it being invisible.

Comment: Given what you just said about word giving you an option to access the file in read-only mode I think it has to with document protection. Check your settings as per https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2013_release/word-2013-unable-to-disable-protected-view-when/c86d7367-5b2a-413f-8a53-713fb8801b1e (see my last comment) - I will be going to bed after this one so please reply fast.

Comment: Sorry to say. But it crashed my pc again.

Comment: That sucks. Try a Microsoft Office repair and installing all updates. Looks like this is computer specific not code. Sorry we could not resolve this one today.

Comment: I am off to bed @MateoVD. I would take any helpful flags and upvotes as thanks. Best of luck! Brett

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I don't know how to do those things.

Comment: It works! I removed some parts from the code you posted and now it works as inteded. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @MateoVD - so glad to hear it all worked out for you. It would be helpful for all future readers if you said what you changed in the code. I will then modify the answer so they can quickly get a result.

Answer (score 0):

On looking at your code more closely, I think the problem is that you don't release the Word objects. Since this code is running from within Excel, those objects are being held in memory, not being released when the macro ends. And Word notoriously has problems with trying to open a document that is still open - because you have an object to it in memory holding it open.

See my changes to your code, below - the `Set [variable] = Nothing` lines.

(Please note that you mix the variable names "TestDoc" and "WordDoc" in your code sample - I just copied it - so the code, as it stands, cannot run correctly.)

```
Set TestDoc = GetObject("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")
If TestDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set Wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Wd Is Nothing Then
        Set Wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        If Wd Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Failed to start Word!", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        f = True
    End If
    Set TestDoc = Wd.Documents.Open("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx")
    If WordDoc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Failed to open help document!", vbCritical
        If f Then
            Wd.Quit
            Set Wd = Nothing
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Wd.Visible = True
Else
    With WordDoc.Parent
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With
End If
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set Wd = Nothing
```

Comment: This puts the macro in an infinite loop. After that it gives me a notification: Microsoft Excel waits till another file has done an OLE-edit. (roughly translated from my language)

When I go into task manager and end WORD it stops.

Comment: @MateoVD I understand that you've solved it, but following up on your comment: I see nothing in the code you gave us that there would be an infinite loop. Another time, you have to give us complete repro details. And you should incorporate setting to Nothing at the *appropriate* place in your code for all non-Excel COM objects.

Comment: What are: complete repro details.? And what do you mean with setting to Nothing. And what are COM objects?

Answer (score 0):

Save the document as a Template (.dotx) and change `.Open()` to `.Add()`.

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

Set WordApp = New Word.Application
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add "C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.dotx"
WordApp.Visible = True

'...

WordDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

Since you have a reference to Word, no need to call `CreateObject("Word.Application")`.

Either remove the reference to Word Library and declare `WordApp` and `WordDoc` as `Object`, or use the `New` keyword.

This way you can open as many instances you want simultaneously.

Comment: This is not what I need Kostas but thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It:

• starts Word if it's not already running.

• opens the document if it's not already open.

• saves & closes the document after editing if it opened it.

• quits Word if it started it.

You can, of course, omit the document close and app quit code if you want to keep the document open. Depending on whether you want to prevent edits to the file being saved, you may want to set ReadOnly:=True, also.

```
Sub OpenWord()
Dim WdApp As Word.Application, WdDoc As Word.Document
Dim bQuit As Boolean, bClose As Boolean
Const StrFlNm As String = "C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx"
If Dir(StrFlNm) = "" Then
  MsgBox "Cannot find the file:" & vbCr & StrFlNm, vbCritical
  Exit Sub
End If
bQuit = False: bClose = True
On Error Resume Next
Set WdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If WdApp Is Nothing Then
  Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  On Error GoTo 0
  If WdApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't start Word.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
  bQuit = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With WdApp
  .Visible = True
  For Each WdDoc In .Documents
    If WdDoc.FullName = StrFlNm Then
      bClose = False: Exit For
    End If
  Next
  If WdDoc Is Nothing Then
    Set WdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=StrFlNm, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=True)
  End If
  With WdDoc
    'Do your document edits here
    If bClose = True Then .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  If bQuit = True Then .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to carefully handling the possibility of having already running Word session as well as not being able to get a Word session

so you may use a helper function:

```
Function GetWord(WordApp As Word.Application) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") 'try getting an already running Word instance
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") ' if unsuccesful then try creating a new Word instance
    GetWord = Not WordApp Is Nothing ' notify the result
End Function
```

and therefore your main code would be refactored as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenWord()
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application

    If Not GetWord(WordApp) Then 'if unsuccesful in getting/creating a Word session then exit sub
        MsgBox "Couldn't get an existing instance or create a new instance of Word", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With WordApp 'reference the Word session you just got/created
        .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        .Visible = True

        On Error GoTo WordErrorHandler:
        .Documents.Open ("C:\Users\mvandalen\Desktop\Test.docx") 

        ' rest of your code exploiting the opened document
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0 'disable Word Error processing

    ' here goes the rest of your code to work without Word object/data



    Exit Sub ' exit not to process statements following 'WordErrorHandler'


WordErrorHandler:
    With WordApp
        If .Documents.Count > 0 Then .Documents.Close '<<< Here it gives error 4605
        .Quit
    End With
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Resume Next        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a function to detect if Word is running and another one to detect if a specific document is open:

```
      Friend Function WordIsOpen() As Boolean
         Dim WindowName As String
         Dim FlagWordIsOpen As Boolean
         Dim p() As Process
         p = Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord")
         If p.Count > 0 Then
            FlagWordIsOpen = True
         Else
            FlagWordIsOpen = False
         End If
         Return FlagWordIsOpen
      End Function
```

Here is the function to detect if a document is already open:

```
      Friend Function DocumentIsOpen(Documento As String) As Boolean
         Dim WindowName As String
         Dim FlagOpenDocument As Boolean
         Dim FileName As String
         Dim PathName As String
         If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Documento) Then
            FileName = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetName(Documento)
         Else
            FileName = Documento
         End If
         Dim lhWndP As Long
         Dim Flag As Boolean
         Flag = False
         Try
            If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, Replace(FileName, System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName), "", VB.CompareMethod.Text)) = True Then
               Flag = True
            End If
         Catch
         End Try
         Return Flag
End Function
```

Here is the function GetHandleFromPartialCaption:

```
Friend Function GetHandleFromPartialCaption(ByRef lWnd As Long, ByVal sCaption As String) As Boolean
         Dim sStr As String
         Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
         Dim lhWndP As Long
         Dim Flag As Boolean
         System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
         Flag = False
         lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
         Do While lhWndP <> 0
            Try
               sStr = GetText(CType(lhWndP, IntPtr))
               If InStr(sStr.ToUpper(), sCaption.ToUpper(), VB.CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                  Flag = True
                  lWnd = lhWndP
                  Exit Do
               End If
            Catch
            End Try
            lhWndP = GetWindow(CType(lhWndP, IntPtr), GW_HWNDNEXT)
         Loop
         Return Flag
End Function
```

Here is the declaration for the API FindWindow:

```
   Friend Declare Function FindWindow Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
```

Here is the function GetText:

```
      Friend Function GetText(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As String
         Dim length As Integer

         If hWnd.ToInt32 = 0 Then
            Return Nothing
         End If
         length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd)
         If length = 0 Then
            Return Nothing
         End If

         Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder("", length)
         GetWindowText(CInt(hWnd), sb, sb.Capacity + 1)
         Return sb.ToString()
      End Function
```

Here is the declaration for GetWindowTextLength:

```
  <DllImport("user32.dll")> Friend Function GetWindowTextLength(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Integer
   End Function
```

Here is the declaration for GetWindowText:

```
  <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowText")>
   Friend Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
   End Function
```

Here is the declaration for GetWindow:

```
   <DllImport("user32.dll")> Friend Function GetWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, uCmd As UInteger) As Long
   End Function
```

... A bit complicated, but I hope it helps!